# How to sort an array of UTF-8 strings?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, utf-8

I currentyl have no clue on how to sort an array which contains UTF-8 encoded strings in PHP. The array comes from a LDAP server so sorting via a database (would be no problem) is no solution. 
The following does not work on my windows development machine (although I'd think that this should be at least a possible solution):

```
$array=array('Birnen', 'Äpfel', 'Ungetüme', 'Apfel', 'Ungetiere', 'Österreich');
$oldLocal=setlocale(LC_COLLATE, "0");
var_dump(setlocale(LC_COLLATE, 'German_Germany.65001'));
usort($array, 'strcoll');
var_dump(setlocale(LC_COLLATE, $oldLocal));
var_dump($array);
```

The output is:

```
string(20) "German_Germany.65001"
string(1) "C"
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "Birnen"
  [1]=>
  string(9) "Ungetiere"
  [2]=>
  string(6) "Äpfel"
  [3]=>
  string(5) "Apfel"
  [4]=>
  string(9) "Ungetüme"
  [5]=>
  string(11) "Österreich"
}
```

This is complete nonsense. Using 1252 as the codepage for `setlocale()` gives another output but still a plainly wrong one:

```
string(19) "German_Germany.1252"
string(1) "C"
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string(11) "Österreich"
  [1]=>
  string(6) "Äpfel"
  [2]=>
  string(5) "Apfel"
  [3]=>
  string(6) "Birnen"
  [4]=>
  string(9) "Ungetüme"
  [5]=>
  string(9) "Ungetiere"
}
```

Is there a way to sort an array with UTF-8 strings locale aware?

*Just noted that this seems to be PHP on Windows problem, as the same snippet with `de_DE.utf8` used as locale works on a Linux machine. Nevertheless a solution for this Windows-specific problem would be nice...*

Comment: It worked just fine here (see my post below), are you sure it has nothing to do with the machine's configuration?

Comment: Note that the sort order depends on the language. In German, A and Ä can sometimes be sorted as if they were the same letter, and sometimes Ä can be sorted as it was in fact "AE". Is Swedish, however, Ä comes at the end of the alphabet. Carl

Comment: You're right - this property is respected by using the correct locale and strcoll() for sorting. The problem here is, that on Windows strcoll() seems to have a problem when the input strings are UTF-8 encoded.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eventually this problem cannot be solved in a simple way without using recoded strings (UTF-8 → Windows-1252 or ISO-8859-1) as suggested by ΤΖΩΤΖΙΟΥ due to an obvious PHP bug as discovered by Huppie.
To summarize the problem, I created the following code snippet which clearly demonstrates that the problem is the strcoll() function when using the 65001 Windows-UTF-8-codepage.

```
function traceStrColl($a, $b) {
    $outValue=strcoll($a, $b);
    echo "$a $b $outValue\r\n";
    return $outValue;
}

$locale=(defined('PHP_OS') && stristr(PHP_OS, 'win')) ? 'German_Germany.65001' : 'de_DE.utf8';

$string="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZÄÖÜabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzäöüß";
$array=array();
for ($i=0; $i<mb_strlen($string, 'UTF-8'); $i++) {
    $array[]=mb_substr($string, $i, 1, 'UTF-8');
}
$oldLocale=setlocale(LC_COLLATE, "0");
var_dump(setlocale(LC_COLLATE, $locale));
usort($array, 'traceStrColl');
setlocale(LC_COLLATE, $oldLocale);
var_dump($array);
```

The result is:

```
string(20) "German_Germany.65001"
a B 2147483647
[...]
array(59) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "c"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "B"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "s"
  [3]=>
  string(1) "C"
  [4]=>
  string(1) "k"
  [5]=>
  string(1) "D"
  [6]=>
  string(2) "ä"
  [7]=>
  string(1) "E"
  [8]=>
  string(1) "g"
  [...]
```

The same snippet works on a Linux machine without any problems producing the following output:

```
string(10) "de_DE.utf8"
a B -1
[...]
array(59) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "a"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "A"
  [2]=>
  string(2) "ä"
  [3]=>
  string(2) "Ä"
  [4]=>
  string(1) "b"
  [5]=>
  string(1) "B"
  [6]=>
  string(1) "c"
  [7]=>
  string(1) "C"
  [...]
```

The snippet also works when using Windows-1252 (ISO-8859-1) encoded strings (of course the mb_* encodings and the locale must be changed then).

I filed a bug report on [bugs.php.net](http://bugs.php.net): [Bug #46165 strcoll() does not work with UTF-8 strings on Windows](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=46165). If you experience the same problem, you can give your feedback to the PHP team on the bug-report page (two other, probably related, bugs have been classified as *bogus* - I don't think that this bug is *bogus* ;-).

Thanks to all of you.

Answer (score 34):

```
$a = array( 'Кръстев', 'Делян1', 'делян1', 'Делян2', 'делян3', 'кръстев' );
$col = new \Collator('bg_BG');
$col->asort( $a );
var_dump( $a );
```

Prints:

```
array
  2 => string 'делян1' (length=11)
  1 => string 'Делян1' (length=11)
  3 => string 'Делян2' (length=11)
  4 => string 'делян3' (length=11)
  5 => string 'кръстев' (length=14)
  0 => string 'Кръстев' (length=14)
```

The `Collator` class is defined in [PECL intl extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php). It is distributed with PHP 5.3 sources but might be disabled for some builds. E.g. in Debian it is in package php5-intl .

`Collator::compare` is useful for `usort`.

Comment: The `ext/intl` extension was actually my life-saver - unfortunately it's not that easy to install on some systems (Mac OS X with bundled PHP for example).

Comment: I often develop on a mac and I never use the bundled e.g. LAMP stack. Instead, install from something like homebrew or macports and you'll save yourself some trouble (and probably add a little more too, but it will be a smaller amount of trouble)

Answer (score 8):

Update on this issue:

Even though the discussion around this problem revealed that we could have discovered a PHP bug with [`strcoll()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strcoll.php) and/or [`setlocale()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php), this is clearly not the case. The problem is rather a limitation of the Windows CRT implementation of [`setlocale()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x99tb11d.aspx) (PHPs `setlocale()` is just a thin wrapper around the CRT call). The following is a citation of the [MSDN page "setlocale, _wsetlocale"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x99tb11d.aspx):

> The set of available languages,
> country/region codes, and code pages
> includes all those supported by the
> Win32 NLS API **except code pages that
> require more than two bytes per
> character, such as UTF-7 and UTF-8. If
> you provide a code page like UTF-7 or
> UTF-8, setlocale will fail, returning
> NULL.** The set of language and
> country/region codes supported by
> setlocale is listed in Language and
> Country/Region Strings.

It therefore is impossible to use locale-aware string operations within PHP on Windows when strings are multi-byte encoded.

Comment: It _is_ a bug in PHP to rely on the OS's ability to collate strings properly, knowing that some os's won't. If a thin wrapper is not enough, PHP should use something else.

Answer (score 4):

This is a very complex [issue](http://unicode.org/reports/tr10/), since UTF-8 encoded data can contain any Unicode character (i.e. characters from many 8-bit encodings which collate differently in different locales).

Perhaps if you converted your UTF-8 data into Unicode (not familiar with PHP unicode functions, sorry) and then normalized them into [NFD or NFKD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_normalization) and then sorting on code points might give some collation that would make sense to you (ie "A" before "Ä").

Check the links I provided.

EDIT: since you mention that your input data are clear (I assume they all fall in the "windows-1252" codepage), then you should do the following conversion: UTF-8 → Unicode → Windows-1252, on which Windows-1252 encoded data do a sort selecting the "CP1252" locale.

Comment: Thanks for that info - I'll have a look at the links. But I doubt that the effort is worth the result as I just want so sort a list of country and state names. Perhaps there is a more simple solution.

Comment: Seems to be a reasonable solution... I'll try sorting the converted array. You're right, that Windows-1252 should cover all the characters used.

Comment: What do you mean convert UTF-8 into Unicode. UTF-8 is a variable-length character encoding for Unicode.

Comment: I mean a byte string of Unicode code points encoded as UTF-8 to the internal representation as a string of Unicode codepoints, whatever that representation would be in PHP (be it UCS-2, UCS-4). I am assuming that PHP has such a concept.

Comment: PHP does not have such a concept :(

Answer (score 1):

I [found this following helper function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6856938/2199525) to convert all letters of a string to ASCII letters very helpful here.

```
function _all_letters_to_ASCII($string) {
  return strtr(utf8_decode($string), 
    utf8_decode('ŠŒŽšœžŸ¥µÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýÿ'),
    'SOZsozYYuAAAAAAACEEEEIIIIDNOOOOOOUUUUYsaaaaaaaceeeeiiiionoooooouuuuyy');
}
```

After that a simple `array_multisort()` gives you what you want.

```
$array = array('Birnen', 'Äpfel', 'Ungetüme', 'Apfel', 'Ungetiere', 'Österreich');
$reference_array = $array;

foreach ($reference_array as $key => &$value) {
  $value = _all_letters_to_ASCII($value);
}
var_dump($reference_array);

array_multisort($reference_array, $array);
var_dump($array);
```

Of course you can make the helper function fit more advanced needs. But for now, it looks pretty good.

```
array(6) {
  [0]=> string(6) "Birnen"
  [1]=> string(5) "Apfel"
  [2]=> string(8) "Ungetume"
  [3]=> string(5) "Apfel"
  [4]=> string(9) "Ungetiere"
  [5]=> string(10) "Osterreich"
}

array(6) {
  [0]=> string(5) "Apfel"
  [1]=> string(6) "Äpfel"
  [2]=> string(6) "Birnen"
  [3]=> string(11) "Österreich"
  [4]=> string(9) "Ungetiere"
  [5]=> string(9) "Ungetüme"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using your example with codepage 1252 worked perfectly fine here on my windows development machine.

```
$array=array('Birnen', 'Äpfel', 'Ungetüme', 'Apfel', 'Ungetiere', 'Österreich');
$oldLocal=setlocale(LC_COLLATE, "0");
var_dump(setlocale(LC_COLLATE, 'German_Germany.1252'));
usort($array, 'strcoll');
var_dump(setlocale(LC_COLLATE, $oldLocal));
var_dump($array);
```

*...snip...*

This was with PHP 5.2.6. btw.

---

The above example is **wrong**, it uses ASCII encoding instead of UTF-8. I did trace the strcoll() calls and look what I found:

```
function traceStrColl($a, $b) {
    $outValue = strcoll($a, $b);
    echo "$a $b $outValue\r\n";
    return $outValue;
}

$array=array('Birnen', 'Äpfel', 'Ungetüme', 'Apfel', 'Ungetiere', 'Österreich');
setlocale(LC_COLLATE, 'German_Germany.65001');
usort($array, 'traceStrColl');
print_r($array);
```

gives:

```
Ungetüme Äpfel 2147483647
Ungetüme Birnen 2147483647
Ungetüme Apfel 2147483647
Ungetüme Ungetiere 2147483647
Österreich Ungetüme 2147483647
Äpfel Ungetiere 2147483647
Äpfel Birnen 2147483647
Apfel Äpfel 2147483647
Ungetiere Birnen 2147483647
```

I did find some [bug reports](http://bugs.php.net/) which have been flagged being [bogus](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=28527)...
The best bet you have is filing a bug-report I suppose though...

Comment: Are you sure, that your PHP file used for testing is UTF-8 encoded? If I use ISO-8859-1 encoding for the file itself, I get the same result you posted above.

Comment: I doublechecked it with a second file (made sure it was UTF-8 encoded) but now it (indeed) seems to replicate your problem, sorry for the crap in that case.

Answer (score 0):

I am confronted with the same problem with German "Umlaute". After some research, this worked for me:

```
$laender =array("Österreich", "Schweiz", "England", "France", "Ägypten");  
$laender = array_map("utf8_decode", $laender);  
setlocale(LC_ALL,"de_DE@euro", "de_DE", "deu_deu");  
sort($laender, SORT_LOCALE_STRING);  
$laender = array_map("utf8_encode", $laender);  
print_r($laender);
```

The result:

> Array
>       (
>       [0] => Ägypten
>       [1] => England
>       [2] => France
>       [3] => Österreich
>       [4] => Schweiz
>       )

Comment: The problem here is that you're going to loose characters that cannot be represented in ISO-8859-1.

Answer (score -1):

Your collation needs to match the character set. Since your data is UTF-8 encoded, you should use a UTF-8 collation. It could be named differently on different platforms, but a good guess would be `de_DE.utf8`.

On UNIX systems, you can get a list of currently installed locales with the command

```
locale -a
```

Comment: I'm using a Windows machine for developing... The appropriate UTF-8 codepage in Windows is 65001 - thats why my locale should be German_Germany.65001.