# How to sort an array considering localization?

Tags: php, sorting, localization

I'm trying to sort an array of names alphabetically (Croatian in this case).

How can I get `Đani` to show up before `Derrick`?

```
$names = array(
    "Đani", "Bill", "Dennis", "George", "Derrick"
);

sort($names);

print_r($names);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Natural sorting algorithm in PHP with support for Unicode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/832709/natural-sorting-algorithm-in-php-with-support-for-unicode)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set the locale appropriately, probably like this:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'hr_HR');
```

And then tell sort to honor the locale:

```
sort($names,SORT_LOCALE_STRING);
```

Comment: Damnit, you posted the exact same answer as me, but I just took a while to find the locale code for Croatia. +1

Answer (score 0):

If you can, you can import them into a MySQL table and use the `ORDER BY` clause to sort, provided you set the right collation for the database/table.

I am sure that there are simpler solutions not requiring a RDMS though.

Take a look to that question as well: [Natural sorting algorithm in PHP with support for Unicode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/832709/natural-sorting-algorithm-in-php-with-support-for-unicode)

Comment: This was my first port of call, but my host is running mYSQL 5.1 which does not support Croatian collation. So SORT BY is effectively broken. I believe this was fixed in 5.6.