# Sorting Issue in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array like this:

```
$country = array(
                    "Afrique du Sud",
                    "Mexique",
                    "Pays-Bas",
                    "Îles Cook",
                    "États-Unis",
                    "Émirats arabes unis",
                    "Viêt Nam"
                );
```

I want to sort this array and I am doing like this:

```
sort($country);
```

I am getting the result as following:

```
Array ( [0] => Afrique du Sud [1] => Mexique [2] => Pays-Bas [3] => Viêt Nam [4] => Émirats arabes unis [5] => États-Unis [6] => Îles Cook )
```

But I am expecting:

```
Array ( [0] => Afrique du Sud [1] => Émirats arabes unis [2] => États-Unis [3] => Îles Cook [4] => Mexique [5] => Pays-Bas [6] => Viêt Nam   );
```

How can achieve my expected result?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3650743/4431269

Comment: you need to add just two line ,[1]. setlocale(LC_COLLATE, 'nl_BE.utf8'); 
[2].usort($country, 'strcoll'); this line add to you can get your desire output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [The Collator class](http://th.php.net/manual/en/class.collator.php) for such cases.

> **Requirement:** (PHP 5 >= 5.3.0, PHP 7, PECL intl >= 1.0.0)
>
> **Description:** Provides string comparison capability with support for appropriate locale-sensitive sort orderings.

```
$collator = new Collator('en_US');
$collator->sort($country);
```

Comment: WORKED..Thanks...!!