# ksort($data,SORT_STRING); does not work

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

My input data ($data):

```
array:45 [▼
  "Ajka" => array:5 [▶]
  "Budapest XX-XXI. kerület" => array:5 [▶]
  "Békéscsaba" => array:5 [▶]
  "Debrecen" => array:5 [▶]
  "Dunaújváros - Szászhalombatta" => array:4 [▶]
  "Győr" => array:5 [▶]
  "Hatvan" => array:5 [▶]
  "Kaposvár" => array:5 [▶]
  "Kiskunhalas" => array:5 [▶]
  "Miskolc - Tiszaújváros" => array:5 [▶]
  "Nagykanizsa" => array:5 [▶]
  "Nyíregyháza" => array:5 [▶]
  "Pécs - Komló" => array:4 [▶]
  "Székesfehérvár" => array:5 [▶]
  "Tatabánya" => array:5 [▶]
  "Tököl" => array:2 [▶]
  "Vecsés, Gyál" => array:3 [▶]
  "Veszprém" => array:5 [▶]
  "Várpalota" => array:3 [▶]
  "Zalaegerszeg" => array:4 [▶]
  "Érd" => array:2 [▶]
]
```

I use this function to reorder the elements of the array:

```
ksort($data,SORT_STRING);
```

But the result of the function is the same:

```
array:45 [▼
  "Ajka" => array:5 [▶]
  "Budapest XX-XXI. kerület" => array:5 [▶]
  "Békéscsaba" => array:5 [▶]
  "Debrecen" => array:5 [▶]
  "Dunaújváros - Szászhalombatta" => array:4 [▶]
  "Győr" => array:5 [▶]
  "Hatvan" => array:5 [▶]
  "Kaposvár" => array:5 [▶]
  "Kiskunhalas" => array:5 [▶]
  "Miskolc - Tiszaújváros" => array:5 [▶]
  "Nagykanizsa" => array:5 [▶]
  "Nyíregyháza" => array:5 [▶]
  "Pécs - Komló" => array:4 [▶]
  "Székesfehérvár" => array:5 [▶]
  "Tatabánya" => array:5 [▶]
  "Tököl" => array:2 [▶]
  "Vecsés, Gyál" => array:3 [▶]
  "Veszprém" => array:5 [▶]
  "Várpalota" => array:3 [▶]
  "Zalaegerszeg" => array:4 [▶]
  "Érd" => array:2 [▶]
]
```

But I expect this to Érd to be removed upper in the result list:

```
array:45 [▼
  "Ajka" => array:5 [▶]
  "Budapest XX-XXI. kerület" => array:5 [▶]
  "Békéscsaba" => array:5 [▶]
  "Debrecen" => array:5 [▶]
  "Dunaújváros - Szászhalombatta" => array:4 [▶]
  "Érd" => array:2 [▶]
  "Győr" => array:5 [▶]
  "Hatvan" => array:5 [▶]
  "Kaposvár" => array:5 [▶]
  "Kiskunhalas" => array:5 [▶]
  "Miskolc - Tiszaújváros" => array:5 [▶]
  "Nagykanizsa" => array:5 [▶]
  "Nyíregyháza" => array:5 [▶]
  "Pécs - Komló" => array:4 [▶]
  "Székesfehérvár" => array:5 [▶]
  "Tatabánya" => array:5 [▶]
  "Tököl" => array:2 [▶]
  "Vecsés, Gyál" => array:3 [▶]
  "Veszprém" => array:5 [▶]
  "Várpalota" => array:3 [▶]
  "Zalaegerszeg" => array:4 [▶]  
]
```

What do I do wrong?
'Érd' should be moved upper in the result list.
Cheers

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/832709/natural-sorting-algorithm-in-php-with-support-for-unicode

Comment: @gaalgergely please update your question with formatted php array

Comment: @BunkerBoy I updated the question.

Comment: @castis Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case the right solution what worked for me is this:

```
setlocale(LC_COLLATE, 'hu_HU.utf8');
uksort($data,'strcoll');
```