# How do I achieve something like MySQL's latin1_general_ci collation in PHP?

Tags: php, sorting, localization, collation, strcmp

I am writing a string compare function to sort medical terms that often contain special accented characters from many different European languages, and I need to somehow achieve a collation similar to MySQL's `latin1_general_ci`.

First, I'm doing some basic munging on the strings to remove spaces, quotes, hyphens, parentheses, etc. The problem comes when I pass the strings on to `strcoll()` using the default locale, because it is not smart enough to consider, for example, an accented e as lexicographically equivalent to a normal e.

I'm wary to use a locale like German or French because it probably will not include all of the special characters I need to consider. Is there a locale that will give me something to similar to the `latin1_general_ci` collation? Or is there maybe another solution?

My naive solution would be to create a large associative array to map accented letters to their regular letter equivalents, then using this with `str_replace()`, but that sounds slow and tedious (and error-prone). I would rather use something built into the language if possible.

Also on that note, does `strcmp()` or `strcasecmp()` respect the collation of the current locale, or is it just `strcoll()` that does this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this:

```
setlocale(LC_COLLATE, 'fr_FR.Latin1', 'fr.Latin1', 'fr_FR.Latin-1', 'fr.Latin-1');
```

`strcmp()` and `strcasecmp()` are not localized.

Comment: Is that French? Won't there be characters in, say, German that won't be accounted for in that collation? Or is FR doing something special?

I did find an "Indo-European" locale and I am currently testing whether it produces the desired result and accounts for the special characters that I'm after.

Comment: It is French, but I'm trying to use the .Latin1 / .Latin-1 modifier to force that charset.  What it takes for that to actually be accepted is the mysterious part.

Comment: I just tried this and oddly enough it worked. Setting a locale other than the default 'C' enables strcoll() to sort all of the accented characters, even ones that aren't in that particular language. For example, setting fr_FR makes strcoll() aware of the german ß character. Odd! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the [iconv](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) functions to help normalize the strings.  That'll handle the accented e to normal e situations. See this related question about [sorting utf8 strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120334/how-to-sort-an-array-of-utf-8-strings/120361), too.

Comment: How exactly can I use iconv? I tried this:

    iconv('ISO-8859-1', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', 'Déjérine-Klumpke')

but it turned the accented e characters into question marks.

Comment: I figured that out. For some reason to do that transliteration, you need to set a locale other than the default 'C' locale.

Comment: Note that it still isn't able to transliterate characters that aren't in that locale. For example, I tried en_US and it still turned the accented e above into a question mark.

I believe the correct solution is still to set a locale other than 'C" and then use strcoll(), as it is seemingly able to collate all of the special characters regardless of the chosen locale.

Comment: have you tried converting the strings to utf and setting the locale to utf8?  In python, i managed to do what you want using http://docs.python.org/library/unicodedata.html.  I -thought- i had seen a php library to do the normalization/decomposition, but I can't find it now.