# Sort rows of a 2d array based on a column's text which may contain accented characters

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, accent-insensitive

I am using this to sort according to last name:

```
usort($fb_friends['data'], "custom_sort");          
function custom_sort($a, $b) { 
    return $a['last_name'] > $b['last_name'];
}

foreach ($fb_friends['data'] as $friend) { 
    echo '<br>'; 
    echo $friend['name']; 
}
```

But - when in last name is accent, e.g. Šiko, Áron, etc, these names are at the end. How can I sort it so that accented characters are positioned near their non-accented letter?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I sort an array of UTF-8 strings in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7929796/how-can-i-sort-an-array-of-utf-8-strings-in-php)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use multi-byte string functions. There is a function called [`strcoll`](http://php.net/strcoll) which seems to suit your needs.

More info:

- [On how to sort an array of UTF-8 strings](http://sgehrig.wordpress.com/2008/09/24/on-how-to-sort-an-array-of-utf-8-strings/)
- [How to sort an array of UTF-8 strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120334/how-to-sort-an-array-of-utf-8-strings)

---

EDIT: added Peter's working code, below

```
setlocale(LC_COLLATE, 'sk_SK.utf8');

usort($fb_friends['data'], 'custom_sort');

function custom_sort($a, $b) {
    return strcoll ($a['last_name'], $b['last_name']);
}

foreach ($fb_friends['data'] as $friend) {
    echo '<br>';
    echo $friend['name'];
}
```

Comment: thank you! this works for me:  setlocale(LC_COLLATE, 'sk_SK.utf8'); 
  usort($fb_friends['data'], "custom_sort");       
  function custom_sort($a,$b) {                    
      return strcoll ($a['last_name'], $b['last_name']);
  }
  

  foreach($fb_friends['data'] as $friend) { 
    echo '<br>'; 
    echo $friend['name']; 
  }

Comment: What if the strings are part of a multiple columns array and we want to sort on multiple columns?

Answer (score 9):

What comes first?

- A
- a
- 文
- ث

This is defined by a **Collation**.

PHP has the Collator class for this: https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.collator.php

Example:

```php
$array = [ 'A', 'a', '文', 'ث' ];

// Brazilian Portuguese
$collator = new Collator('pt_BR');

$collator->asort( $array );

print_r( $array );
```

Returns:

```
Array
(
    [1] => a
    [0] => A
    [3] => ث
    [2] => 文
)
```

Now with a Chinese collation `new Collator('zh')`:

```
Array
(
    [2] => 文
    [1] => a
    [0] => A
    [3] => ث
)
```

You can try it yourself here: https://3v4l.org/0vsBR