# Utf8 Sort Array

Tags: php, sorting, php-5.3

i have some problems with sorting an array.

List

```
0 => string 'Australien' (length=10)
1 => string 'Belgien' (length=7)
2 => string 'Botswana' (length=8)
3 => string 'Brasilien' (length=9)
4 => string 'Bulgarien' (length=9)
5 => string 'Burma' (length=5)
6 => string 'China' (length=5)
7 => string 'Costa Rica' (length=10)
73 => string 'Ägypten' (length=8)
```

But Ägypten should be after Australien.
I already tried with the Collator class but our client wont install the extension.

Comment: Do you have any other names like "Ägypten" ?

Comment: I am sure this link will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7929796/how-can-i-sort-a-utf-8-string-in-php

Comment: You didnt read my whole question ? I already tried the Collator. And yes Its more than one.

Comment: Hi Noaaah...If you read down below the link I sent you it has more than Collator answer. Like the one Narendra wrote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`setlocale`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php) along with first parameter `LC_COLLATE` and second locale with `en_US.utf8` and simply sort using [`usort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcoll.php) along with [`strcoll`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) try as

```
setlocale(LC_COLLATE, 'en_US.utf8');
$array = array('Australien','Belgien','Botswana','Brasilien','Bulgarien','Burma','China','Costa Rica','Ägypten');
usort($array, 'strcoll'); 
print_r($array);
```

[<kbd>**Demo**</kbd>](https://eval.in/419488)

Comment: In this case the locale should probably be `de_DE.UTF-8`, but yes, this *should* work.

Comment: Thanks for reffering. I'll update it but it'll generate the same as that of shown by OP [Check This](https://eval.in/419493) @deceze

Comment: Its wont work... `   setlocale(LC_COLLATE, 'de_DE.UTF-8');
   $this->utf8_encode_deep($list);

   usort($list['continents'], 'strcoll');
  

   die(var_dump($list['countries']));`

Comment: What's not working @noaaah did you checked the [demo link its working fine](https://eval.in/419488)

Comment: @NarendraSisodia Well idk for me it wont work i put my code in the comment

Comment: Well I've replaced `de_DE.UTF-8` along with `en_US.utf8` to let it work as required @noaaah

Comment: @noaaah 1) What in the world does `utf8_encode_deep` do?! 2) You need to ensure that those locales you're setting are actually installed on the system. Perhaps they're named differently on yours.