# How can I sort an array by accented keys in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, collation

I have accented values as keys of an array in PHP. I want to sort by key, but it seems that the Collator object doesn't have this option, destroying the keys instead.

```
<?php
$arr = ['Brasil' => 3, 'África do Sul' => 5];
$collator = new Collator('pt_BR');
$collator->sort($arr);
var_dump($arr);

$arr = ['Brasil' => 3, 'África do Sul' => 5];
$collator->asort($arr);
var_dump($arr);

$arr = ['Brasil' => 3, 'África do Sul' => 5];
$collator->sortWithSortKeys($arr);
var_dump($arr);
?>
```

This will display:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>int(3)
  [1]=>int(5)
}
array(2) {
  ["Brasil"]=>int(3)
  ["África do Sul"]=>int(5)
}
array(2) {
  [0]=>int(3)
  [1]=>int(5)
}
```

How can I achieve my desired sorting below?

```
array(2) {
  ["África do Sul"]=>int(5)
  ["Brasil"]=>int(3)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New advice:

Use `uksort()` and pass the `Collator` class's `compare` method as the callback.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/lCDqG))

```
uksort(
    $arr,
    [new Collator('pt_BR'), 'compare']
);
var_export($arr);
```

---

Old advice:

I've never used this class before, but I believe this is a simple matter of misunderstanding [the PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/collator.sortwithsortkeys.php).  To be perfectly honest, I was tricked by the method name as well.  It doesn't sort by keys -- as you can see in the demo in the manual, the values are being sorted.

Because your keys are (by definition) unique, you can safely call `array_keys()` to create a temporary indexed array where the original keys are now values.  Then map the original data to the sorted array.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/RohbY))

```
$arr = [
    'Alemanha' => 1,
    'China' => 5,
    'EUA' => 13,
    'Itália' => 2,
    'África do Sul' => 1
];

$collator = new Collator('pt_BR');
$keys = array_keys($arr);
$collator->sort($keys);
foreach ($keys as $key) {
    $result[$key] = $arr[$key];
}
var_export($result);
```

Or ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/16etR))

```
$collator = new Collator('pt_BR');
$keys = array_keys($arr);
$collator->sort($keys);
var_export(
    array_replace(
        array_flip($keys),
        $arr
    )
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'África do Sul' => 1,
  'Alemanha' => 1,
  'China' => 5,
  'EUA' => 13,
  'Itália' => 2,
)
```