# Strcoll sorting order

Tags: php, sorting

I have an initial array with names and ID-s that have to be sorted, based on family names while following the local alphabet:

```
$names = array(
    "134" =>    "Mati Vänt",
    "24" =>     "Mati Vint",
    "11" =>     "Mati Wint",
    "12" =>     "John Zareem",
);
```

and the function to sort them (big thanks to Alma Do):

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'et_EE.utf8');
uasort($nimed, function($x, $y)
{
    return strcoll(
    end(preg_split('/\s+/', $x)),
    end(preg_split('/\s+/', $y))
);
});
```

Which gives the result: John Zareem, Mati Vint, Mati Wint, Mati Vänt.

It is correct in the sense that Z comes before V like in the local alphabet, but why are family names starting with one letter (V) mixed with names with a different first letter (W)? Is there perhaps a way to avoid it?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't know anything about your alphabet, but it may have something to do with the way you're setting the locale. I took off the `.utf8` and [it seems to work](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/74c7222c4262bf5fa3255b5b4dc23fd953d98a48).

Comment: It seems the .utf8 may still be necessary - otherwise Vänt (ä) comes before Vint (i) etc, which isn't correct by the local alphabet:
(A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S, Š, Z, Ž, T, U, V, W, Õ, Ä, Ö, Ü, X, Y)

Comment: Yep, checked it again - with strcoll() everything else is ordered perfectly, then the family names starting with V.. then suddenly W.. then V again. Maybe it would make more sense to create an array with the alphabet and sort the names array by it?

Comment: Thanks for posting your alphabet. Unfortunately, I haven't found an easy way around it, but I did stumble across a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/120334/how-to-sort-an-array-of-utf-8-strings) which suggests that what you're experiencing may be a possible limitation of the standard PHP library and UTF-8 encoded strings. The most upvoted answer to that question uses the Collator class from the intl extension. If I find anything else that might be of use I'll let you know.