# Unexpected Sort Behavior PHP Collator::asort for values in format YYYY-MM-DD

Tags: php, sorting, collation, asort

I am finding a unexpected sorting behavior with string values in the formtat `YYYY-MM-DD` such as `2016-12-16` when using [`Collator::asort`](http://php.net/manual/en/collator.asort.php). Using PHP's normal `asort`, there is no issue. With the Collator version, it looks like there is some bug and it seems to then sort by the array keys instead.

Edit: I am using PHP Version 5.6.29 for this test.

I made a little sample program to show the issue:

```
<?php

$list["off-to-the-races"] = "2015-04-14";
$list["new-years-2015"] = "2015-01-01";
$list["ground-hog-day"] = "2015-02-02";
$list["back-to-the-future"] = "2015-08-12";

$locale = setlocale(LC_COLLATE, 0);
$col = Collator::create($locale);

$res_val = collator_get_locale( $col, \Locale::VALID_LOCALE );
$res_act = collator_get_locale( $col, \Locale::ACTUAL_LOCALE );

echo "<pre>";

printf( "Valid locale name: %s <br /> Actual locale name: %s <br />",
        $res_val, $res_act );


echo "<br /><br />Raw List: <br />";
print_r($list);


$col->asort($list);
echo "<br /><br />\$col->asort(\$list): <br />";
print_r($list);

echo "<br /><br />Collator error message: <br />";
echo $col->getErrorMessage();

asort($list, $sort_flags);
echo "<br /><br />asort(\$list) (without collation): <br />";
print_r($list);
```

---

Here is my output on the test server:

```
Valid locale name: en_US_POSIX 
Actual locale name: en_US_POSIX 


Raw List: 
Array
(
    [off-to-the-races] => 2015-04-14
    [new-years-2015] => 2015-01-01
    [ground-hog-day] => 2015-02-02
    [back-to-the-future] => 2015-08-12
)


$col->asort($list): 
Array
(
    [back-to-the-future] => 2015-08-12
    [ground-hog-day] => 2015-02-02
    [new-years-2015] => 2015-01-01
    [off-to-the-races] => 2015-04-14
)


Collator error message: 
U_ZERO_ERROR

asort($list) (without collation): 
Array
(
    [new-years-2015] => 2015-01-01
    [ground-hog-day] => 2015-02-02
    [off-to-the-races] => 2015-04-14
    [back-to-the-future] => 2015-08-12
)
```

As you can see, when using `$col->asort($list)` it is not in the original order, but has clearly not be sorted as expected.

The whole point of using the `YYYY-MM-DD` way to represent a date as a string is that if sorted like a string, it would be in both alphabetical and chronological order in most implementations.

Note, if I add the following test case with `$sort_flag` set:

```
$col->asort($list, 1 );
echo "<br /><br />\$col->asort(\$list, 1): <br />";
print_r($list);
```

it will work correctly:

```
$col->asort($list, 1): 
Array
(
    [new-years-2015] => 2015-01-01
    [ground-hog-day] => 2015-02-02
    [off-to-the-races] => 2015-04-14
    [back-to-the-future] => 2015-08-12
)
```

While this is an adequate work around if you know all of your values will be in this format, I would expect it to also work as a natural or string sort - for cases where your values are mixes of date strings and other arbitrary strings.

I am not sure if this is locale/collation specific. Is there anyway to debug further?

Comment: What is your PHP version? Did you try using different sort flags? What about different locales? (I cannot test as I seem to have forgotten to update php on this test machine).. is this a similar issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/120334/how-to-sort-an-array-of-utf-8-strings

Comment: PHP Version 5.6.29 -  Did not test different locales yet. Trying to use defaults as they would be on my client's server and using collator because it baked into the framework I am using. I tried different `$sort_falgs` only `1` gave something that looked correct.