# How to sort non-english strings in php

Tags: php

How to display the following array string in alphabetically without using the collator method

```
$country = array('Ägypten','Afghanistan', 'Äquatorialguinea', 'Albanien');
```

**My code is:**

```
function compareASCII($a, $b) {
    $a1 = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $a);
    $b1 = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $b);
    return strcmp($a1, $b1);
}

usort($country, 'compareASCII');
```

**Output:**

```
Array ( [0] => Ägypten [1] => Äquatorialguinea [2] => Afghanistan [3] => Albanien )
```

**Expected Output:**

```
 Array ( [0] => Afghanistan [1] => Ägypten [2] => Albanien [3] => Äquatorialguinea )
```

How to get expected output?

Thanks for advance!!!

Comment: [How to sort an array of UTF-8 strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/120334/how-to-sort-an-array-of-utf-8-strings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can made manual (simple version, can be extended):

```
$country = array('Ägypten','Afghanistan', 'Äquatorialguinea', 'Albanien');

usort ($country,function($a,$b){
    $a=str_replace(array('Ä','Ö','Ü'),array('A','O','U'),$a);
    $b=str_replace(array('Ä','Ö','Ü'),array('A','O','U'),$b);
    return strcmp($a,$b);
});

print_r($country);

//Result
//Array ( [0] => Afghanistan [1] => Ägypten [2] => Albanien [3] => Äquatorialguinea )
```

Comment: @vinoth But read about the diff. between `mb_str_replace` and `str_replace`. It is possible that in some cases the function may not work right. Its all about encoding. But as long this function fits to your belongings take it :-)