# PHP usort with utf8 characters (czech)

Tags: php, utf-8

I've tried to search in many threads here and over google, but nothing worked for me... I have to sort string array, which contains strings with czech (utf8) characters, like [a,b,z,**č**,v,**ř**]
I am using setLocale and usort, but I also tried classic sort, asort etc...

Here is code I am using right now (but not working..)
Thanks for any help!

```
    $sortDocTypes = function ($a, $b) {
        SetLocale(LC_ALL, "cs_CZ");
        return strcoll($a, $b);
    };

    usort($generatedDocumentList, $sortDocTypes);
```

Comment: Did you try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/120334/how-to-sort-an-array-of-utf-8-strings

Comment: Read more here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/120334/how-to-sort-an-array-of-utf-8-strings

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions First :P

Comment: @jjag3r
I did, but Collator didn't work for me neither...

Comment: There is more than `Collator` explaint, it is a big topic, please read more, maybe all from the link. @jjag3r :-)

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions So I tried everything and nothing worked for me..