# Ksort working fine but 1 item is not correct. Same thing happens on multiple cases

Tags: php, wordpress

I have an array populated dynamically from customers data in a foreach loop. It looks like this :
"Émilie Champagne" => "array",

```
$customers = get_customers_from_orders( $customers_orders ); // Get an array of customers data
if ( $customers !== 'empty' ) {
  
  $customers_items = array();
  foreach ( $customers as $customer ) {
    $html = '';
    // THE CUSTOM LIST ITEM
    $html .= '<li order_id="'.$customer['order_id'].'" email="'.$customer['email'].'">';
    $html .= $customer['name'];
    $html .= '</li>';
    $customers_items[$customer['name']] = $html;
  }
  ksort( $customers_items );
  foreach ( $customers_items as $customer_item ) {
    $customer_list .= $customer_item;
  }
}
```

When i use the ksort, its working but only one customer at the end is not sorted correctly.

[Screenshot showing the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OkJWn.png)

You can see the last item is starting with letter "E".

The same thing happens on 3 others ksort function on the same page.

Any idea how i could fix this?

Comment: Salut Gabriel, note that `É` is not == to `E` for a computer.  Check the flags for `ksort` (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php), maybe the locale could be useful.  Check this too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120334/how-to-sort-an-array-of-utf-8-strings

Comment: FYI, refrain from putting images in your question, especially since it is text.  And to provide a good [mcve], you should add a complete example of your data array.  We could then try your code.